# returning cursor results causes "stack size exceeded" error

Tags: meteor

I have a page that lists a company's profile and shows its open jobs. I use iron-router to get the companies profile info, but use a Meteor.call to get active jobs once the page has been loaded. However, when I return a cursor it throws a stack size exceeded error.

organization.js

```
Template.organization.rendered = function() {
    Meteor.call('getActiveJobs', function(error, jobs){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(jobs);
        }
    });
}
```

collection

```
Meteor.methods({
.....
    getActiveJobs: function(){
        return Jobs.find({organizationId: user.profile.organizationId});
    }
.....
});
```

this throws a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

However, I can return

```
return Jobs.find({organizationId: user.profile.organizationId}).fetch();
```

without an error, but I'm trying t return the cursor so it's easier to work with using handlebars, but I don't quite understand why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, that the values returned from your method need to be transferred from server to client in the JSON format. It follows that you cannot return Objects which are not JSON-serializable *(there are small exceptions here, but we can forget about them for now).*

If you want to return a cursor you should use `Meteor.publish` instead of `Meteor.methods`, so

```
Meteor.publish('activeJobs', function () {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
  return Jobs.find({organizationId: user.profile.organizationId});
});
```

Also, remember to call `Meteor.subscribe('activeJobs')` on the client as soon as you need this data set.

Comment: but doesn't .fetch() return an array of the objects, which is an object itself (which works)?

Comment: Yes, of course. But it is serializable. You can safely return an array of objects from a method but you will not have a cursor this way.